# Custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a child class of AuthorizeAttribute named CheckArticleExistence.

I would like to set an attribute using the parameter that I receive in the action. Like this:

```
[CheckArticleExistence(Id=articleId)]
public ActionResult Tags(int articleId)
{
...
}
```

I want to use the articleId to check if that article exists in the database, and if it doesn't I can trigger something different using the OnAuthorization method.

Is there any way?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this done at the OnAuthorization stage?

Comment: Please can you be more clearer about what you actually want to do with articleId?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think You can get the *articleId* from the *AuthorizationContext*, so you don't need to pass it as a property of the attribute.

You can just do:

```
[CheckArticleExistence]
public ActionResult Tags(int articleId)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This one worked (thanks!):

```
[CheckArticleExistence]
public ActionResult Tags(int articleId)
{
    ...
}

...

public class CheckArticleExistenceAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private int articleId;

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {

        this.articleId = int.Parse(filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString());

        if (!Article.Exists(articleId))
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put a method in your repository to check for the existence of an article.

```
public ActionResult Tags(int articleId)
{
    if (repository.ArticleExists(articleID))
    {
        // Do your thing
    }
    else
    {
        return view("NotFound"); // or do something else
    }
}
```

Or you can simply attempt to retrieve the article, and check for a null object.

```
public ActionResult Tags(int articleId)
{
    var article = repository.GetArticle();
    if (article !=null)
    {
        // Do your thing
    }
    else
    {
        return view("NotFound"); // or do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. This would probably be the best thing to do to be honest.

Comment: But this one is the obvious way... I would like to use an AuthorizeAttribute because if I decide to change the way I handle the article nonexistence, I do not need to change all the actions that check if the article exists. Anyway, thank you

Comment: Hopefully your repository always has just one way to check.  You can change your implementation there.

Comment: this gives a bit more control over the user experience in the case of a non-existent id. the filter would also work, but then you have "user logic" outside of the controller. filters should probably be for malicious or exceptional cases.