# Restrict access to a certain action based on ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Say that you have a controller named Buildings and that every user in the system have a set of buildings that he/she administrates. If you have an Edit-action in your controller that you can access with /Buildings/Edit/{id} is there a nice and simple way to implement some kind of authorization attribute that only allows access to this site if the id you are trying to edit is a part of the logged in users set of buildings. Or do you have to handle this yourself in your controller?

regards
Freddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can use [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx).
- [Check out this SO too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482135/custom-authorizeattribute/1482191#1482191)
- Check this post: [asp.net mvc attributes actionfilterattribute and why you might want to use them](http://byatool.com/index.php/lessons/asp-net-mvc-attributes-actionfilterattribute-and-why-you-might-want-to-use-them/)

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, you can derive from the [Authorize attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) to define your own authorization for an action method. There's an example of using it in [this blog post](http://blog.geniar.com/index.php/2009/05/aspnet-mvc-testing-a-custom-authorize-filters/).