# Data based entitlements/authorization in ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, entitlements

My google skills are failing me on this. I'm looking for the "right way" to do data based entitlements in ASP.Net MVC (3).

With regular entitlements where one just need to know the user and the route can be done with the `[Authorize]` attribute, but this doesn't appear to work with data based entitlements b/c of the need to have a connection to the data store.

Is the obvious approach of inserting a check into the action methods the right way?

Comment: What is a "data based entitlement?"  Do you mean "security" or "authorization?"  Try looking for "table-based security in ASP.NET MVC".

Comment: @Robert -exactly, I've updated the title to reflect this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482135/custom-authorizeattribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the obvious approach of inserting a
>   check into the action methods the
>   right way?

That's what I do.

```
if (!userHasAuthorization)
   return view("Unauthorized");
```

It's by far the simplest way.

To make sure you only have to do "userHasAuthorization" once, you can put a method in your repository or service layer that checks for authorization, and use that in place of the boolean value `userHasAuthorization`.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what "data based entitlements" are. I do believe that custom action filters will get you what you want. This lets you manage whatever you need around authorization with having the context of the route, user, etc. Gives more fine grained control. Also gives you the re usability so you dont need to plug if statements into your action methods.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609.aspx

Comment: I think what he's asking is: How do you look up authorization values from the database without tightly coupling your custom `AuthorizeAttribute` to the database?  It's something I've often wondered myself.  The custom `AuthorizeAttribute` does not have access to your repository, but by the time you've already entered the Action Method, it is too late.

Comment: Then I would go with this approach I mentioned here, the custom action filter lets you return before entering the action method.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom action filter derived from the `[Authorize]` attribute that uses the data store to check authorization.

Comment: Any specifics on how to do that - meaning, how does one give the MyAuthorize class an instance of `IDBConnection` ?